# Only use Integer numbers not decimal

Tags: reactjs

I need to solve something. I've got my number picker And my issue is following:

"Cannot read property 'value' of null"

I only want to insert integer values in my NumberPicker.

That's my NumberPicker.

```
  import React from "react";
  import NumberPicker from 'react-widgets/lib/NumberPicker';
  import simpleNumberLocalizer from "react-widgets-simple-number";
  import * as NumericInput from "react-numeric-input";


    simpleNumberLocalizer();

  const handleBlur = (e) => {
     if (e.currentTarget.value === '0') e.currentTarget.value = '1'
  }

    const handleKeypress = (e)  => {
          const characterCode = e.key
             if (characterCode === 'Backspace') return

             const characterNumber = Number(characterCode)
            if (characterNumber >= 0 && characterNumber <= 9) {
        if (e.currentTarget.value && e.currentTarget.value.length) {
          return
        } else if (characterNumber === 0) {
          e.preventDefault()
       }
      } else {
                e.preventDefault()
     }
    }



 const numberPicker = ({
     step,
     precision,
     input,
     placeholder,
     label,
     handleBlur,
     handleKeypress,
     meta: { touched, error },
   ...rest
 }) => {return(
    <div className='form-group'> 

 <label forname={input.name}>{label}</label> <br />
       <NumericInput
       {...rest}
       placeholder={placeholder}
       selected={input.value ? new NumericInput(input.value) : null}
          onChange={input.onChange}
         onKeyDown={(changedVal) => handleKeypress(changedVal)}
         onBlur={(changedVal) => handleBlur(changedVal)}
         min='1'
         step='1' 
         style={{
           wrap: {
               background: '#E2E2E2',
               boxShadow: '0 0 1px 1px #fff inset, 1px 1px 5px -1px #000',
               padding: '2px 2.26ex 2px 2px',
               borderRadius: '6px 3px 3px 6px',
               fontSize: 32
           },
           input: {
               borderRadius: '4px 2px 2px 4px',
               color: '#988869',
               padding: '0.1ex 1ex',
               border: '1px solid #ccc',
               marginRight: 4,
               display: 'block',
               fontWeight: 100,
               textShadow: '1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'
           },
           'input:focus' : {
               border: '1px inset #69C',
               outline: 'none'
           },
           arrowUp: {
               borderBottomColor: 'rgba(66, 54, 0, 0.63)'
           },
          arrowDown: {
               borderTopColor: 'rgba(66, 54, 0, 0.63)'
           }
       }}
         className='form-control'
  />
    <div className='text-danger' style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>
         {touched && error}
       </div>
       </div>
);
};
  export default numberPicker;
```

I'm inserting integer values And when I'm doing click in other field, app crashes and I've got error "Cannot read property 'value' of null"

What am I doing wrong?, I'm doing wrong something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component is expecting `handleBlur` and `handleKeypress` to be provided as props.

Basically, what's happening here is that you've redefined `handleBlur` and `handleKeypress` within the scope of the `numberPicker` function, and they are undefined because you didn't pass them when you used the component.

Remove `handleBlur` and `handleKeypress` from the argument destructuring:

```
const numberPicker = ({
     step,
     precision,
     input,
     placeholder,
     label,
     handleBlur, // delete this line
     handleKeypress, // delete this line
     meta: { touched, error },
   ...rest
 })
```

Comment: I deleted those two lines just now. This the is line when I've got the issue:  if (e.currentTarget.value === '0') e.currentTarget.value = '1'.  I've been mistaken. Sorry. The error is: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: @FranciscoArias Honestly, I'm confused about what you're event trying to do with these functions. `react-numeric-input` seems to handle everything you want to do. I'd delete your `handleBlur` and `handleKeypress` functions completely and rely on the `min` and `step` props on `<NumericInput>`. Just make sure you use numbers instead of strings: `min={1}`, not `min='1'`.

Comment: I solved it just now. I'd to replace e.currentTarget.value for e.target.value in these lines. const handleBlur = (e) => {
     if (e.currentTarget.value === '0') e.currentTarget.value = '1'
  }  //and   if (e.currentTarget.value && e.currentTarget.value.length) { in handleBlur and handleKeyPress, respectively.